# SAS proc transpose duplicate values issue

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I need your help, please!

I'm doing a proc transpose on SAS, from a table that as only unique lines. However it is returning the following error

> ERROR: The ID value "'OUTROS_CANAIS_Fatura Eletrónica'n" occurs twice in the same BY group.
> NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
> ID_CLIENTE=xxxxxxxxxx

When I check the original table the ID_CLIENTE xxxxxxxxxxx has two lines:

> ID_CLIENTE    MOTIVO  Nr_Solicitacoes

> xxxxxxxxxx    OUTROS_CANAIS_Fatura Eletrónica - adesão    1

> xxxxxxxxxx    OUTROS_CANAIS_Fatura Eletrónica - cancelamento  1

I believe it is the '-' that is causing the issue (that comes with the original data), since they are clearly two different values.

Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT: I've managed to replace the '-' value, however it still returns the same error...**

Thank you!!

Comment: Show your `Proc TRANSPOSE` statements

Comment: Hello @Richard I've figured it out. Its in my answer.

But thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Proc TRANSPOSE` `ID` statement turns data values into columns names when pivoting data.  Column names are limited to 32 characters (and column labels are limited to 200 characters).  Your ID values when truncated to 32 characters are the same value and you get the 'occurs twice' LOG message.

You can add a new variable to distinguish the id values and use the `IDLABEL` statement to store the original id values in the variable labels.

Example:

`idnum` is added to the data and is used to distinguish the id values.  *If you have many id values a hash can be used to dynamically assign a unique idnum for each id value*

```
options validvarname = v7;

data have;
  id = 'xxxxxxxxxx OUTROS_CANAIS_Fatura Eletrónica - adesão';
  idnum = 1;
  count = 1;
  output;

  id = 'xxxxxxxxxx OUTROS_CANAIS_Fatura Eletrónica - cancelamento 1';
  idnum = 2;
  output;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want;
  id idnum;
  idlabel id;
  var count;
run;

proc contents data=work.want;
run;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

SAS only allows 32 bites columns... It was a coincidence that ended in '-'.